# RequestDispatcher from servletcontext versus request

Tags: servlets, requestdispatcher

What is different between these two code lines and when should we use each of them?

1.

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(“result.jsp”);
```

2.

```
RequestDispatcher view = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(“/result.jsp”);
```

Comment: What is "VS" in this context? Not Visual Studio, I presume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) `RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(“result.jsp”);`

Here,

- view is relative to the current request. you have to pass relative path of jsp/html
- for chaining two Servlets with in the same web application.

[java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)) says,

> The pathname specified may be relative, although it cannot extend
>   outside the current servlet context. If the path begins with a "/" it
>   is interpreted as relative to the current context root. This method
>   returns null if the servlet container cannot return a
>   RequestDispatcher.
>
> The difference between this method and
>   ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String) is that this
>   method can take a relative path.

2)    RequestDispatcher view = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(“/result.jsp”);

Here,

- view is relative to the root of the Servlet context, you have to pass absolute path of jsp/html
- for chaining two web applications with in the same/different servers.

[java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)) says,

> The pathname must begin with a "/" and is interpreted as relative to
>   the current context root. Use getContext to obtain a RequestDispatcher
>   for resources in foreign contexts. This method returns null if the
>   ServletContext cannot return a RequestDispatcher.